# Transcendence of solutions of $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i^x = 1$

Tags: transcendence

I am currently doing things related to the [Akra–Bazzi theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akra%E2%80%93Bazzi_method). One element in that theorem is the following:

For $n>0$ and sequences of real numbers $a_i, b_i$ of length $n$, where all $a_i>0$ and all $b_i\in (0;1)$, we consider the unique real number $x$ such that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i b_i^x = 1$$

My question is: when is $x$ rational/algebraic/transcendental?

For example, for the equation 
$$\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^x + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x = 1$$
$x$ is in $(1.1519623;1.1519624)$. It *looks* like a transcendental number to me, but I have no idea how to show that it is or is not.

Comment: Every number looks like a transcendental number. Also, every number looks like an algebraic irrational, and every number looks like a rational number.

Comment: And certainly every number also looks like a computable number.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Of course the solution of
$$
\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^x + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x = 2
$$
is rational, and the solution of
$$
\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)^x + \left(\frac{3}{4}\right)^x = \frac{13}{12}
$$
is rational.  And of course there are many more like this.  So any proof that your number is transcendental seems unlikely to me.  See? I can do "seems to me" statements, too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Schanuel's conjecture implies that if $x$ is an algebraic irrational, 
$n^x$ for natural numbers $n$ are linearly independent over the rationals:
see Will Sawin's answer to [this recent question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/204064/for-what-real-t-is-nt-n-geq-1-linearly-independent-over-mathbbq/204075#204075) for a proof.   It's easy to extend this to positive rationals.  Thus Schanuel implies that if the $a_i$ and $b_i$ are rational, $x$ will either be rational or transcendental. 
So (if you're willing to accept Schanuel) you just have to check for rational solutions, which for something like $(1/3)^x + (3/4)^x = 1$ is not hard.

Comment: That looks pretty interesting, thanks. However, I'm not entirely sure how to prove that the solution is not rational for a case like that.